# Forms diferentes na mesma linha

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

To com dois form no meu código, e o HTML deu uma quebra de linha entre os dois.
Gostaria que ambos fossem impressos um do lado do outro, para economizar espaço na tela.

Gostaria de saber como fazer isso utilizando CSS ou Bootstrap 3.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
  

<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title text-center">USUARIO, esta solicitação ainda está pendente de sua aprovação!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body text-center">

        <form action="/Ti01/AprovaSolicitacao" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
            <input htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, readonly = readonly }" id="CadastroID" name="CadastroID" type="hidden" value="1">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-finish" name="aprova" value="Aprovar">
        </form>
        <form action="/Ti01/RejeitaSolicitacao" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
            <input htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, readonly = readonly }" id="CadastroID" name="CadastroID" type="hidden" value="1">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-danger" name="rejeita" value="Rejeitar">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Impresso que vc fala é quando for imprimir mesmo no papel, ou na tela?

Comment: Desculpa, na tela mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vc tem que usar o Grid, `row>col` e usar a classe `text-left/right` para alinhar os `btns` no centro.

Não precisa de CSS extra, dentro da sua `panel-body` vc coloca uma `row`, e cada form em uma `col-xs-6`, depois vc coloca na `col` a classe `text-lef` ou `text-right` para alinha o `btn`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código abaixo

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title text-center">USUARIO, esta solicitação ainda está pendente de sua aprovação!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body text-center">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                <form action="/Ti01/AprovaSolicitacao" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <input htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, readonly = readonly }" id="CadastroID" name="CadastroID" type="hidden" value="1">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-finish" name="aprova" value="Aprovar">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                <form action="/Ti01/RejeitaSolicitacao" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <input htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, readonly = readonly }" id="CadastroID" name="CadastroID" type="hidden" value="1">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-danger" name="rejeita" value="Rejeitar">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```